# Sharepoint 2010 COM groups silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, sharepoint

I'm getting the groups with:

```
var GruposSP = web.SiteGroups;
ClientContextLocator.ClientContextHome.Load(GruposSP, groups => (groups.Include(g => g.Users)), groups => (groups.Include(g => g.LoginName)));
```

And it throws me:

> "Access Denied". You do not have
>   permission to perform this action or
>   access this resource

Is there any way to get the users from a site without permission?

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

With the next line you get the users and groups from the web

```
ListItemCollection usersList = ctx.Web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
```